# Haptic feedback with RIO unit

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, audiounit, haptic-feedback, taptic-engine

If I have AVAudioSession configured with .playAndRecord category and a remote IO unit running, what's the besy way to enable haptic feedback on button presses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIFeedbackGenerator` to create haptic feedback in your iOS app. You can use one of the below options depends on your requirement:

> UIImpactFeedbackGenerator: Use impact feedback generators to indicate
> that an impact has occurred. For example, you might trigger impact
> feedback when a user interface object collides with something or snaps
> into place.

Example:

```
let impact = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator()
impact.impactOccurred()
```

> UISelectionFeedbackGenerator. Use selection feedback generators to indicate a change in selection.

Example:

```
let impact = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
impact.selectionChanged()
```

> UINotificationFeedbackGenerator. Use notification feedback generators to indicate successes, failures, and warnings.

Example:

```
let impact = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
impact.notificationOccurred(.success)
```

You can read more info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator

Comment: It would not work if you have AVAudioSession with playAndRecord or record categories